# httpd with SSL doesn't start in RHEL 6.3

Tags: apache, certificate, mod-ssl

I'm running 4 servers with the same config:

RHEL Server 6.3
Apache 2.2.15
mod_ssl_x86_64

In 3 servers, the SSL configuration it's working, but in the last serv, i've got the next error:

Unable to configure verify locations for client authentication.

This is my ssl.conf

http://pastebin.com/Um4NV4vT

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Solved, just follow this steps.

http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/weblinux2/apache/ch11_10.htm

Thanks.